# Pending Custom Link in Menu

Tags: menus, links

If I try to add a custom link to a menu, it says "Pending" and won't save. If I hit save, it disappears. This only happens to custom links - pages, posts, categories all work fine.

I've googled this issue and they suggest switching to a default theme and back, or repairing the wp_postmeta database. I've done both with no success. No clue what to do next, and this is driving me mad. I'm a beginner too...

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this. I just needed to add a title to the custom link in the options BEFORE adding it to the menu. How stupid is that?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Disable all plugins. Update your nav. If it works then we know a plugin is the cause.
> 2. Switch to a theme by team WordPress (eg. TwentyTwenty). Update your nav. If it works then we know the theme is the cause.
> 3. Switch to a different browser. Update your nav. If it works then a browser incompatibility issue or browser extension/plugin is the
>      cause.
>
> [Source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-to-menu-now-not-working/#post-9522382)

In my case, solution #1 worked.